# How to Concat JSON objects Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

I have two Json Array objects with the same structure and I want to concat them together using Swift. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
var jsonArray1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}, {'name': "dofug", 'id':23}];
var jsonArray2 = [{'name': "goud", 'id':1}, {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52}];

jsonArray1 = jsonArray1.concat(jsonArray2);
```

[image]

Comment: var jsonArray1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}, {'name': "dofug", 'id':23}];
var jsonArray2 = [{'name': "goud", 'id':1}, {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52}];
jsonArray1 = jsonArray1.concat(jsonArray2);

Comment: My Data as above. this is example that I want

Comment: That's Javascript, not Swift code

Comment: so I will get 
jsonArray1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}, {'name': "dofug", 'id':23}, 
{'name': "goud", 'id':1}, {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52}];

Comment: Yes, I knew it but this is example concept

Comment: @user3404359 Can you please care to add reason of unaccepting the answer. And that is after a year

Answer (score 1):

From your image it is look like that you have two array of `[[String: AnyObject]]` type, So you can append all the element of jsonArray2 to jsonArray1 like this

**First Way**

```
jsonArray1 += jsonArray2
```

**Second Way**

```
jsonArray1.extend(jsonArray2) // Swift 1.2
jsonArray1.appendContentsOf(jsonArray2) // Swift 2
```

**In Swift 3.0 you can append like this**

```
jsonArray1.append(contentsOf: jsonArray2)
```

Answer (score 0):

parse using SwiftyJSON and concat-

```
var JSONObject = JSON(json["content"].arrayObject! + json["content"].arrayObject!)
```